# Allowing multiple files to be processed through one module

Tags: vb.net, pdf, module

I've created a program to modify security settings of a .pdf file.

This works fine for one file - but I want to allow editing multiple .pdf's with the touch of one button and am struggling to make it work.

I have pasted the code for my GUI below, "Modify_PDF" is the module that runs the pdf security modification code.  Is it possible to run multiple files through this module from here?

```
Dim source_file As String = ""

'''   Handles clicking of the 'Open file' button
Private Sub open_button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles open_button.Click

    Dim input As FileStream = Nothing

    'Set filter to only allow compatible files
    OpenFileDialog.Filter = "PDF documents (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
    'Allow multiple files to be opened
    OpenFileDialog.Multiselect = True

    'open the file selection dialogue
    If OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        Try
            input = OpenFileDialog.OpenFile()
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error opening file: " & vbCrLf & Ex.Message)
        Finally
            'Check this again to ensure no exception on open. 
            If (input IsNot Nothing) Then
                input.Close()
            End If
        End Try

        If input IsNot Nothing Then
            source_file = OpenFileDialog.FileName
            If Modify_PDF.process_file(source_file, "") Then
                PDF_name.Text = Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog.FileName)

                input.Close()
                modify_button.Enabled = Modify_PDF.process_file(source_file, "") 'Allow report to be created if processing succeeds
            End If
        End If

    End If

End Sub



'''   Handles clicking of the 'Modify PDF' button
Private Sub generate_button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles modify_button.Click
    Modify_PDF.modify_pdf(source_file, source_file, "")
End Sub
```

Comment: you'll need to loop on the results of the `OpenDialogFile`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#Anchor_2

Comment: The `FileNames` property will be an array of selected files.  process them in a loop.  Please edit your tags to use the correct ones (hover over them and read the words)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
If OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    Try
         For Each FileName as String in OpenFileDialog.FileNames
             'Do something with the filename here
         Next
    Catch ...
```